# Google Drive PHP v3 API File Metadata

Tags: php, file, google-drive-api, metadata

Google specifies the metadata in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource.

If I do

```
$parameters['fields']="*";
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

Then I indeed get pretty much all that.
If I just do

```
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

i.e. no fields setting I get a subset, but some fields such as createdTime are now blank - and that is one I need.
Google recommend (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter) listing only the fields you need to improve performance, but just about everything I put in fields gets an error "Invalid field selection" (tested in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22createdTime%22%7D)

```
$parameters['fields']="name,parents,mimeType,filesize,createdTime,modifiedTime";
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

Any clues as to how this works?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list using `name,parents,mimeType,filesize,createdTime,modifiedTime` using Drive API v3 with googleapis for php.

#### Modification points:

- There is no fields of `filesize`. In this case, it's `size`.
- When the field values of `name,parents,mimeType,size,createdTime,modifiedTime` are set for the method of "Files: list" of Drive API v3, please use `files(name,parents,mimeType,size,createdTime,modifiedTime)`. I think that the reason of your error message of `Invalid field selection name` is due to this.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
$parameters['fields']="name,parents,mimeType,filesize,createdTime,modifiedTime";
```

To:

```
$parameters['fields']="files(name,parents,mimeType,size,createdTime,modifiedTime)";
```

#### References:

- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: Yes - I was aware of this and wanted to accept but I see no button! I searched the page and no sign of one!

Comment: Thanks - it was definitely not there originally but is now!

Comment: @Dave Torr Thank you for your response.